# What controls to fix this Filter?

Tags: gui-design, filter, faceted-search

https://www.scic.com/schedule

I'm looking to replace the filters on the right side of the page and need to know some of the possiblities.

For the date selector, I'm looking at using: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Any other ideas as far as the other criteria is concerned? each of the criteria should also be multiselect.

Needs to be mobile friendly because we are moving that direction.

Comment: What problems are you seeing with the existing filters? What are the goals or requirements that the replacement filters need to address?

Comment: The user comments are that they are unwieldy and not easy to use, especially the Programs selector accordion at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing the accordion with a [multiselect](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) box?

Comment: Don't think they're going to go for that one.

Comment: What, no other ideas?

Comment: I couldn't find anything that doesn't move items from the complete list to the selected list.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying.